# The Parallelogram Identity for an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given inner product space $V$, I would like to prove the inequality
$$\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|^2 + \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2
= 2(\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 + \|\mathbf{y}\|^2).$$

We see that
$$\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|^2 + \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2
= \langle\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\rangle
+ \langle\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rangle,$$

which by linearity
$$=\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\rangle + \langle\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\rangle
+ \langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rangle - \langle\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rangle.$$

I've been trying to figure out how to go about this proof using linearity
in the second argument of an inner product, but my textbook does not say
that linearity necessarily holds in the second component. If it does, how
would I go about the rest of this proof? If not, should I be potentially
using some aspect of conjugate symmetry to prove this statement?

Comment: inner products are symmetric...

Comment: The inner product It is by definition bilinear, it is not simply linear. Hence you can "using linearity in the second argument" (its are your words).

Comment: @DanRust  Complex inner products are conjugate symmetric.  That is $<x,y>=<y,x>^{*}$

Comment: @Mollie that is not an inequality but an equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle x,x+y\rangle=\langle x+y,x\rangle^{*}=\langle x,x\rangle^{*}+\langle y,x\rangle^{*}=\langle x,x\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle$
$\langle y,x+y\rangle=\langle x+y,y\rangle^{*}=\langle x,y\rangle^{*}+\langle y,y\rangle^{*}=\langle y,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle$
$\langle x,x-y\rangle=\langle x-y,x\rangle^{*}=\langle x,x\rangle^{*}-\langle y,x\rangle^{*}=\langle x,x\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle$
$\langle y,x-y\rangle=\langle x-y,y\rangle^{*}=\langle x,y\rangle^{*}-\langle y,y\rangle^{*}=\langle y,x\rangle-\langle y,y\rangle$

Plug this back into the expression that you've gotten so far using linearity and you should end up with the identity.